# Appending (or extending?) a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So here's a list of lists:

```
comment = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
           ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
           ['h']]
```

Say there's a function `classify_predict` that classifies each element of `comment` to either `0`, `1`, or `2`.

```
class = []

for i in range(0, len(comment))
    for j in range(0, len(comment[i]))
        result = classify_predict(comment[i][j])
        class.append(result)
```

**What I'm getting**: then the result is just a list (so not corresponding to `comment`)

```
print(class)

[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**What I want to get**: What should I do to get the next result?

```
print(class)

[[0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an intermediate list to store the results for the sub-lists:

```
results = []

for i in range(0, len(comment))
    result = []
    for j in range(0, len(comment[i]))
        result.append(classify_predict(comment[i][j]))
    results.append(result)
```

or in a single line, using nested list comprehensions:

```
results = [[classify_predict(item) for item in sublist] for sublist in comment]
```

As a side note, don't use built-ins (such as `class`) as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You can map each sub-list to the `classify_predict` function:

```
classifications = [list(map(classify_predict, lst)) for lst in comment]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use keyword `class`.

The code you may want is as follows.

```
result = []
for com in comment:
    record = []
    for c in com:
        record.append(classify_predict(c))
    result.append(record)
```